# Relationships of Opportunities, Quotes, Contracts and orders

Tags: opportunity, administration, quote, order, contracts

We are using Opportunities, quotes, Contracts and Orders in our Org. This is a brand new instance of Salesforce and we are in the process of streamlining the sales and order process.

The proposed solution is

There is one opportunity, quotes are generated for the opportunity once the quote is accepted then opp is won and a contract is created and when the contract is signed then the order is generated and activated.

Now there are instances when the order is been executed the client comes up with some changes to the order like he would want to add some line items or make changes to existing line items. We would need to make these changes to be reflected in the contracts as well.

What is the best process to be followed in this scenario?

One option we have is to clone the quotes and lineitems and then send it to the client. Deactivate the previous contract and generate a contract based on the new quote and create orders based on the new contract and deactivate the old order.

Are there any other better ways of handling this scenario?

Answer (score 4):

There are few thing which should be considered when using Contract:-

1. Contract are signed for Organisation and signed by Contact of the Organisation.
2. Opportunity can be associated with one Contract. Contract is parent of Opportunity.
3. Once the Contract is activated it can be deleted or cloned but not deactivated.
4. Order are also can be Activated and Deactivated (in some conditions)

So, for Sales Cycle:-

1. Consider the Contract is something which define business process agreement between your organisation and other organisation for services you are providing. Avoid narrowing to Order only.
2. An Orgnaisation can have multiple active contracts so multiple Opportunity can be associated with same or different Contract.
3. Do not activate Contract until it is finalized. In case it requires change, create new Contract and get it signed again. Associate the Opportunity with the new Contract. Delete the previous one.
4. Do not activate order until it finalized. In case it require changes, deactivate and make changes and re-activate.

I hope above would help you figure out answers. But there are many use cases which people use.  It is directly proportional to creativity.

Comment: @Prady let me know if you have outstanding query regarding answer. I would happy to answer.

Comment: Could you eloborate on "Avoid narrowing to Order only" .

Comment: @Prady By your question It looks like that each order is having a Contract. So. their are fair chance of frequent Contract modification.  We should setup the Contract considering it would have minimum modifications.  Contract should be flexible to manage few order changes. However, it is very dependent to business rule and use case.

Comment: Yes, that what i proposed to do, Everytime a contract is created and signed i create a new order and deactivate the old order. Is there a better way to handle this? Or is it better to modify the existing order and relate that order to new contract?